# Chef - print multiple attributes to the log

Tags: chef-infra, aix, chef-recipe, rubocop

Background. In my environment I don't have direct access to the Servers my recipe will be applied to and the best I can do is to get the log files after a unsuccessful run.

I would like to send the platform and most importantly the version to the log file

```
log 'OS version'
   message { node['platform_family'] node['platform_version'] }
   level  :warn
end
```

However Rubocop complains and I suspect that I am not formatting the variables correctly.

What is the correct way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to interpolate them into a string. Like: `message "#{node['platform_family']} #{node['platform_version']}"`

Comment: Thank you ! BTW off hand can you point me to the documentation that discusses this ? It would be helpful in a cases when I needed to know if I was on a box running OS version 6.x or higher and I assume I would need to convert the attribute to a string before I compare. Thanks again

Comment: Doesn't seem to be OS-specific. Guess you could experiment on Linux or any other Unix-like platform.

Comment: Also attributes are whatever type they are, the issue is that the `log` resource can only log a string.